# Docker - Can not connect my .Net Core API to my SQLServer

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker, asp.net-core

I'm working a Microservice Project in DDD.
I have 3 API and 3 databases ( 1 database per API )
We will conecentrate on Trainingcourses.API and Trainingcourses.Db

When I call the controller of Trainingcourses.API, which use the database, I get this error :
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/varHd.png)

Docker Compose File :

```
services:
  trainingcourses.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
    depends_on:
      - trainingcourses.db
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro

  trainingcourses.db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
    container_name: "TrainingCourses.Db"
    hostname: "TrainingCoursesDb"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "1234Test4321"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - "1434:1433"
```

AppSettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CvGamifyTrainingCourse": "Server=TrainingCoursesDb;Database=TrainingCoursesDb;User=sa;Password=1234Test4321;"
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: Why do you bind port 1434 to 1433? Shouldn't that line just be `- "1433:1433"`?

Comment: @DavidG it could be too, but doesn't matter. As it could be 1435:1433... But thanks for your answer :-)

Comment: Sure, but then your connection string won't work as shown here.

Comment: @DavidG : I tried with 1433. It doesn't change anything ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the two containers, listed as services, must communicate together you've to relay on a `network` defined in the docker system.

The `ports` defines ports exposed over the docker's host to the rest of the host's LAN.

I would suggest altering your `docker-compose.yml` this way:

```
services:
  trainingcourses.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
    depends_on:
      - trainingcourses.db
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
    networks:
      - net01

  trainingcourses.db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
    container_name: "TrainingCourses.Db"
    hostname: "TrainingCoursesDb"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "1234Test4321"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - "1434:1433"
    networks:
      - net01

networks:
  net01:
```

New is the `networks:` entry for each services and `netowrks:` section at the end of the file.

The ports `1434` und `8000` will be exposed over the docker host to other LAN-connected clients.